# Java JNI EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, gcc, java-native-interface, cygwin

I'm new to JNI and attempting to get a simple Hello World program to work using Windows 7 and cygwin's gcc compiler.  Here's the various components:

**Hello.java:**

```
public class Hello {
    public static native void sayHello();

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.loadLibrary( "Hello" );
        sayHello();
    } // end main
} // end class Hello
```

I then execute the following list of commands to build the .h file:

```
javac Hello.java
javah Hello
```

This automatically builds the Hello.h file. For completeness, that's here:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Hello */

#ifndef _Included_Hello
#define _Included_Hello
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Hello
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

I then build the corresponding Hello.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Hello.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHello( JNIEnv *env, jclass c ) {
    printf( "Hello World\n" );
}
```

Then, I compile/link the c code using the following command:

```
gcc -I/cygdrive/c/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/include -I/cygdrive/c/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/include/win32 -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o Hello.dll Hello.c
```

Finally, I recompile the java file.  (Do I even really need to do this?):

```
javac Hello.java
```

I'm using this Makefile (and I'm also relatively new to building Makefiles) to complete all the steps with one make command:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=
LDFLAGS=
JAVALIB="/cygdrive/C/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/include"
JAVALIBWIN32="$(JAVALIB)/win32"

all: Hello.dll
        javac Hello.java

Hello.dll: Hello.h
        $(CC) -I$(JAVALIB) -I$(JAVALIBWIN32) -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o Hello.dll Hello.c


Hello.h: Hello.class
        rm -f Hello.h
        javah Hello

Hello.class: Hello.java
        javac Hello.java

clean:
        @rm -f *.dll *.class
```

Once I execute the program (using the command "java Hello"), I receive this error:

```
$ java Hello
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000001800f9309, pid=7292, tid=5616
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [cygwin1.dll+0xb9309]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\dev\JNI\hs_err_pid7292.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

And, the resultant error log looks like:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000001800f9309, pid=7292, tid=5616
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [cygwin1.dll+0xb9309]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000253e000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5616, stack(0x0000000002830000,0x0000000002930000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000030

Registers:
RAX=0x00000000002c0000, RBX=0x0000000000000001, RCX=0x00000000002c0000, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000000292f0e0, RBP=0x000000000292f1d0, RSI=0x000000000292f14c, RDI=0x000000000292f14c
R8 =0x000000000292f14c, R9 =0x8080808080808080, R10=0xfefefefefefefeff, R11=0x0000000551bc10ac
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000000cf70258, R14=0x000000000292f258, R15=0x000000000253e000
RIP=0x00000001800f9309, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000292f0e0)
0x000000000292f0e0:   000000000cf70258 0000000000000000
0x000000000292f0f0:   000000000292f1b0 00000000701e8e37
0x000000000292f100:   000000000292f1b0 0000003200390032
0x000000000292f110:   000000000292d680 0000000180185145
0x000000000292f120:   000000000cf70258 000000000253e000
0x000000000292f130:   000000000253e000 0000000002577cd0
0x000000000292f140:   000000000cf70258 000000000292f258
0x000000000292f150:   000000000292f170 0000000000000002
0x000000000292f160:   000000000000000c 000000007013a904
0x000000000292f170:   0000000551bc3030 000000000000000b
0x000000000292f180:   00000001802653c0 0000000000000001
0x000000000292f190:   000000000cf70258 0000000040000020
0x000000000292f1a0:   000000000f017ced 000000018011ae5b
0x000000000292f1b0:   0000000040000000 000000000253e000
0x000000000292f1c0:   000000000cf70258 0000000040000020
0x000000000292f1d0:   000000000292f240 000000000f025e34 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000001800f9309)
0x00000001800f92e9:   1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 56 53 48 83 ec 28 89 cb 48
0x00000001800f92f9:   89 d6 e8 d0 4b 04 00 48 8b 10 49 89 f0 48 89 c1
0x00000001800f9309:   4c 8b 4a 30 89 da 48 83 c4 28 5b 5e 49 ff e1 0f
0x00000001800f9319:   1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 56 53 48 83 ec 28 89 cb 48 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000000002c0000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000000002c0000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000292f0e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000253e000
RBP=0x000000000292f1d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000253e000
RSI=0x000000000292f14c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000253e000
RDI=0x000000000292f14c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000253e000
R8 =0x000000000292f14c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000253e000
R9 =0x8080808080808080 is an unknown value
R10=0xfefefefefefefeff is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000551bc10ac is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x000000000cf70260} 'sayHello' '()V' in 'Hello'
R14=0x000000000292f258 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000253e000
R15=0x000000000253e000 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000002830000,0x0000000002930000],  sp=0x000000000292f0e0,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [cygwin1.dll+0xb9309]
C  [cygwin1.dll+0x145145]
C  [cygwin1.dll+0xdae5a]
C  0x0000000040000000

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  Hello.sayHello()V+0
j  Hello.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+5
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000001e093800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8452, stack(0x000000000ecc0000,0x000000000edc0000)]
  0x000000001e011000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2924, stack(0x000000001e460000,0x000000001e560000)]
  0x000000000d56f000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7784, stack(0x000000000ee60000,0x000000000ef60000)]
  0x000000000d566800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6812, stack(0x000000000eba0000,0x000000000eca0000)]
  0x000000000d563000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3936, stack(0x000000000e9c0000,0x000000000eac0000)]
  0x000000000d561800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=432, stack(0x000000000e590000,0x000000000e690000)]
  0x000000000d507000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7632, stack(0x000000000e8b0000,0x000000000e9b0000)]
  0x000000000d500000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4284, stack(0x000000000e690000,0x000000000e790000)]
=>0x000000000253e000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5616, stack(0x0000000002830000,0x0000000002930000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000000d4fa800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000000e490000,0x000000000e590000] [id=8520]
  0x000000001e097800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001e620000,0x000000001e720000] [id=3404]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 2621K [0x000000076b200000, 0x0000000770700000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65536K, 4% used [0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b48f680,0x000000076f200000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076fc80000,0x000000076fc80000,0x0000000770700000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f200000,0x000000076f200000,0x000000076fc80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 0K [0x00000006c1600000, 0x00000006cc100000, 0x000000076b200000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c1600000,0x00000006c1600000,0x00000006cc100000)
 Metaspace       used 2341K, capacity 4486K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 261K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000002fc0000,0x00000000037c0000] byte_map_base: 0xffffffffff9b5000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000070814040
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000004420000, 0x00000000083c8000)
 End Bits:   [0x00000000083c8000, 0x000000000c370000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000250000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1084Kb max_used=1084Kb free=244675Kb
 bounds [0x000000000f010000, 0x000000000f280000, 0x000000001e010000]
 total_blobs=247 nmethods=17 adapters=144
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.050 Thread 0x000000001e011000    6       3       java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::ensureCapacityInternal (16 bytes)
Event: 0.050 Thread 0x000000001e011000 nmethod 6 0x000000000f11bad0 code [0x000000000f11bc40, 0x000000000f11be88]
Event: 0.050 Thread 0x000000001e011000   14       3       java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::append (29 bytes)
Event: 0.051 Thread 0x000000001e011000 nmethod 14 0x000000000f11d250 code [0x000000000f11d3c0, 0x000000000f11d6c8]
Event: 0.051 Thread 0x000000001e011000   15  s    3       java.lang.StringBuffer::append (13 bytes)
Event: 0.051 Thread 0x000000001e011000 nmethod 15 0x000000000f11d850 code [0x000000000f11d9e0, 0x000000000f11dee8]
Event: 0.051 Thread 0x000000001e011000   16       3       java.io.WinNTFileSystem::isSlash (18 bytes)
Event: 0.051 Thread 0x000000001e011000 nmethod 16 0x000000000f11e110 code [0x000000000f11e260, 0x000000000f11e450]
Event: 0.055 Thread 0x000000001e011000   17       3       java.lang.String::equals (81 bytes)
Event: 0.055 Thread 0x000000001e011000 nmethod 17 0x000000000f11e8d0 code [0x000000000f11ea60, 0x000000000f11efb0]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.026 Thread 0x000000000253e000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x000000076b20cdf0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\srƒ­fÎÝ‘š?
Event: 0.026 Thread 0x000000000253e000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x000000076b20d080) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jÐW

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.054 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection
Event: 0.054 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection done
Event: 0.054 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper
Event: 0.054 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper done
Event: 0.054 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray
Event: 0.054 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray done
Event: 0.054 loading class java/lang/Void
Event: 0.054 loading class java/lang/Void done
Event: 0.054 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper
Event: 0.054 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013fbd0000 - 0x000000013fc07000     C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe
0x0000000076df0000 - 0x0000000076f98000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076bd0000 - 0x0000000076cef000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefcdd0000 - 0x000007fefce3c000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00000000748b0000 - 0x0000000074945000     C:\Windows\System32\SYSFER.DLL
0x000007fefe7e0000 - 0x000007fefe8bb000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefdd00000 - 0x000007fefdd9f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefeb10000 - 0x000007fefeb2f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefe6b0000 - 0x000007fefe7dd000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000076cf0000 - 0x0000000076dea000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefeaa0000 - 0x000007fefeb07000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefe640000 - 0x000007fefe64e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefef90000 - 0x000007feff059000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefb510000 - 0x000007fefb704000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefe000000 - 0x000007fefe071000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefe320000 - 0x000007fefe34e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefe080000 - 0x000007fefe189000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000007fefcae0000 - 0x000007fefcb11000     C:\Windows\system32\nvinitx.dll
0x000007fefcad0000 - 0x000007fefcadc000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x000000000f000000 - 0x000000000f006000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\detoured.dll
0x000007fef9e90000 - 0x000007fef9ec1000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvd3d9wrapx.dll
0x000007fefe8c0000 - 0x000007fefea97000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x000007fefcd90000 - 0x000007fefcdc6000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x000007fefe230000 - 0x000007fefe307000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefddf0000 - 0x000007fefdff3000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefce40000 - 0x000007fefce5a000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000007fef9e60000 - 0x000007fef9e82000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvdxgiwrapx.dll
0x000000005b3d0000 - 0x000000005b4a2000     C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000070010000 - 0x0000000070893000     C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef6650000 - 0x000007fef6659000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefdda0000 - 0x000007fefdded000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefe310000 - 0x000007fefe318000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefa7c0000 - 0x000007fefa7fb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000076fc0000 - 0x0000000076fc7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000071370000 - 0x000000007137f000     C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000071170000 - 0x0000000071199000     C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.dll
0x0000000066750000 - 0x0000000066766000     C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefcf70000 - 0x000007fefdcf9000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefcbb0000 - 0x000007fefcbbf000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x0000000551bc0000 - 0x0000000551bd8000     C:\dev\JNI\Hello.dll
0x0000000180040000 - 0x0000000180600000     C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
0x000007fef40d0000 - 0x000007fef41f5000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
java_command: Hello
java_class_path (initial): .
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
PATH=C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\bin;.;C:\cygwin64\lib\lapack
USERNAME=gary.valley
SHELL=/bin/bash
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.18409)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 69 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

Memory: 4k page, physical 16680200k(12576164k free), swap 33358544k(28455468k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_45-b14), built on Apr 10 2015 10:34:15 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Thu Apr 23 22:46:03 2015
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

I've been following the guide essentially line by line from this [site](http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/helloWorld/java.html).  The only thing I couldn't replicate is the -mno-cygwin option because I'm using gcc version 4.9.2 and that option is unrecognized.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks much!

Comment: Just to keep everyone up to date:  The second javac compile is unnecessary.  Also, I was able to make this software work on an Ubuntu linux distribution.  It definitely has to do with Cygwin because it's pretty simple once on the linux box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely turned out to be the Cygwin environment.  I moved to an Ubuntu distribution and the linked guide worked as advertised.

Comment: # C  [cygwin1.dll+0xb9309] 
says it actually crashed in cygwin.   I build on a jni library on linux and cross compile the dll to Windows aswell.